# How should I include a CSS file to be used when my published JavaScript package runs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, npm

I have a Typescript project which will be published via NPM. The package is an SDK which runs in the browser. It needs to display content in a `dialog` element which I am appending to the page when my code is called.

One aspect I am struggling to get my head around is how to go about providing CSS styling for elements added to the page at runtime like this, outside of the limited amount I can achieve with e.g. `element.style.height = "100%"` and so on.
Aside from being extremely clunky to maintain, I'm not sure it's possible to access media queries or styling of pseudo elements such as `dialog::backdrop` this way.

What I *think* I want/need is to simply have a regular CSS file included in my project which I can either:

- Add to the user's page at runtime via a `link` tag pointed to the file
- Read and insert the contents of said file dynamically via a `link` tag inserted by JavaScript
- ...or any other possible approach

Are there any good common approaches to including styles with libraries like this that are published for others to use on their sites?

Afterthought: Do I perhaps need to just publish and host the static stylesheet via an entirely separate process and just append a `link` pointed at that? If possible I'd prefer an approach more integrated with the project itself, though.

Comment: Does the end user already have to add a link to the JS file from your packag to their HTML file?  If so, it seems easy enough to just let them know they need to link to a CSS file as well.  Overall though, yes a real CSS file is much better than writing inline styles everywhere.

Comment: @FiniteLooper Currently the setup is such that my package will be added to users' projects via NPM as a project dependency and included that way, rather than via a link tag in their markup (although this may be added as an alternative option).